# How could I get Garbage Collection statistics from a weblogic server?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, weblogic

We have a weblogic server on which our application is hosted. A few days ago, we had `OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` problem. Now I would like to investigate why it occured. So I googled about getting garbage collection statistics. I got a few command line options to get GC details like `–XX:+PrintGCDetails` and `–XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps`.

What I want to know is how and when to use these commands. Sine they are command line options, does it mean that they can only be used while starting the server? Because, if it is so, I would only be able to get details of the upcoming GC cycles which would be of no use to me since I am trying to dig into a problem that occured couple of weeks ago. Or is there some other way by which I can get the details of a past garbage collection?

Comment: You can use [jstat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstat.html) to monitor the number of GCs that have been run and how long they took.  It will also show you the JVM memory usage which may offer some clues.  Just be sure to use the binary which matches the vendor and versino of you JVM otherwise you may not get all the values.

Comment: If you start to see the problem again, you can do a thread/stack dump on a running server like `jstack {pid} > stack-trace.log` and maybe get some insight as well. There is nothing you can do to see details of past garbage collection without the command line `-XX` options already there

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to add the below `JVM` arguments to enable `GC` activities log, this arguments generates a log file that contains the all `GC` activities during the application live time

> -XX:+PrintGCDetails
>
> -Xloggc:[VALID_PATH\gc.vgc]

Also you can analyze the file using a `HP Jmeter` tool, it's a nice GUI tool that have a nice visual representation for the `GC` activities.